# ways to add two ontap method flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:workplan_beta_test/pages/updateworkplan.dart';
    import 'package:workplan_beta_test/pages/workplan.dart';
    
    Map<int, Color> color = {
      50: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .1),
      100: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .2),
      200: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .3),
      300: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .4),
      400: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .5),
      500: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .6),
      600: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .7),
      700: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .8),
      800: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .9),
      900: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, 1),
    };
    MaterialColor colorCustom = MaterialColor(0xFF4fa06d, color);
    
    class MenuWorkplan extends StatelessWidget {
      late final Color? color;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Workplan'),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: colorCustom,
          ),
          body: new ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
                return Center(
                  child: ChoiceCard(
                    choice: choices[index],
                    item: choices[index],
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Workplan(),
                          ));
                    },

     onTap: () {
error in this line
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Workplan(),
                          ));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              })));
    }
```

I want to add two onTap() methods in listView inside ChoiceCard Widget in order to track two times click. Is that possible? Any alternative help is appreciable. I am a newbie to flutter. Below is my sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not use the same property twice in one widget. Explain your use case better, please.

Comment: you just wrap your ChoiceCard with Inkwell and used onTap, I hope it will be working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call the same methods (in your case onTap() method) more than one time. But you can go with some alternative approaches depending upon your use case. For example, you can wrap your ChoiceCard Widget with some other widget with onTap method available.